# Working With Very Large String Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, string

There is a array of about 50.000 words. indexing takes a lot of time. Sometimes it stops. If there are about 1.000 words, no problem.

Arrays in another class.

I tried these:

```
let arr: [String] = ["str1", "str2", ...]
```

or

```
let arr: [String] = [

"str1",

"str2",

...]
```

or

```
let arr1: [String] = ["str1", "str2", ..., "str9999"]

let arr2: [String] = ["str10000", "str10001", ..., "str19999"]

...

let arr5: [String] = ["str40000", "str40001", ..., "str50000"]
```

What is the best way to work with large arrays? Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Don't put all of that data in code. Put it in a database or at least a plist file.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you so much. the plist is really very handy. It's very light now and it works fine. I upgraded my computer's memory by 16 GB. :)